# Scheduled Database Backup job fails due to lack of disk space

Tags: sql-server, backup

Two of my scheduled SQL Server backups failed over the weekend because of a lack of space.

The `C:` drive has 25.3 GB of free space out of 400 GB. The primary space taker is SQL.

- 149.9 GB `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\BACKUP`
- 139.7 GB `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\DATA`

Any suggestions as to how to fix this problem? Please help! I'm a rookie DBA confronted with this issue

Comment: Provide more space?

Comment: Change to simple recovery mode and shrink transaction logs.

Comment: Maybe don't backup to the same server that is hosting the database either.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal If the database is under `FULL` recovery model it will be better to start performing transaction log backups regularly.

Comment: Are you using backup compression. If not use it, it does saves lot of space

Comment: What version are you running? see @Shanky 's comment depending on version and edition

Answer (score 1):

(Can post this as comment due to lack of rep)

This link could be helpful to you:
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2531/sql-server-compressed-backups-disk-space-needs/

Comment: I doubt he has SQL Server Enterprise edition.

Comment: depending on the version he might not need to